ntfs-3g on macos: hd is writable, rsync fails and cp gives error messages
I have compiled ntfs-3g on macos, ventura 13.6.6, and I use it with macfuse.
I have mounted the external disk:  the HD is writable and I can write to it, but I get some errors with rsync -avz and cp -p.
rsync: mkstemp <destination> failed: Operation not permitted (1)

rsync fails
cp: <origin>: could not copy extended attributes to <destination>: Operation not supported on socket
cp: utimensat: <destination>: Permission denied
cp: fchmod: <destination>: Operation not permitted

cp copies, but cannot change timestamps and modes.
I read online that it is due to a difference in filesystems, and the solution is to transfer with gpc or with rsync without changing owner or group. If this is property of ntfs, I just don't understand why this does not happen with linux, as far I remember.
I would like to know if there is some other solutions that are available.
